# How to create new directory in Netatalk 3.x (AFP) share with group write permission

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, afp, netatalk

I have 2 users :

- userA
- userB

both in the group :

- studio

They are using the same shared folder **workdir**

if **userA** creates a new folder inside **workdir**, it looks like :

```
drwxr-sr-x+  2 userA studio 4096 Feb 22 14:20 newFolder
```

Then **userB** doesn't have write permissions to this newly created folder.

What can I must do to force create new folder with group write permissions, to achieve this :

```
drwxrwsr-x+  2 userA studio 4096 Feb 22 14:20 newFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in `/etc/afp.conf` in the **volume** section:

```
directory perm = 0770
```

Then restart netatalk service and test.